# How to store a tree on the disk and make add/delete/swap operations easy

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, tree, structure

All right, this question requires a bit of reading on your side. I'll try to keep this short and simple.

I have a tree (not a binary tree, just a tree) with data associated to each node (binary data, I don't know what they are AND I don't know how long they are)

Each node of the tree also has an index which isn't related to how it appears in the tree, to make it short it could be like that:

[image]

The index number represents the order the user WANTS the tree to be navigated and cannot be duplicated.

I need to store this structure in a file on the disk.

My problem is: **how to design a flexible disk storing format that can make loading and working on the tree as easy as possible**.

In fact the user should be allowed to

- Create a child block to an element (and this should be easy enough, it's sufficient to add data to the file paying attention to avoiding duplicated indices)
- Delete a child (I should prompt the user "do you want to delete all this node's children as well? or should I add its children to its parent?"). The tricky part about this is that deleting a node could also free up an index, and I can't let the user use that index again when adding another node (or the order he set could be messed up), I need to update the entire tree!
- Swap an index with another one

I'm using C++ and Qt and by now I thought of a lot of structures with a lot of fields like this one

```
struct dataToBeStoredInTheFile
{
    long data_size;
    byte *data; //... the data here

    int index;
    int number_of_children;
    int *children_indices; // ... array of integers
}
```

this has the advantage to identify each node with its respective index, but it's highly slow when swapping indices between two nodes or deleting a node and updating each other node's index because you have to traverse all the nodes and all their "children_indices" arrays.

Would using something like an "hash" to identify each node be more flexible?
Should I use two indices, one for the position in the tree and one for the user's index? If you have any better idea to store the data, you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using something like [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), then you don't have to worry about the actual format when save on disk, and can concentrate on effective in-memory solution.

**Edit:** Re-reading your question I see you are using Qt, in that case it should have it's own serialization framework that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it doesn't have to be a SINGLE file, you could use the file/directory structure to represent your tree, where each node corresponds to a single file (w/ a directory for each interior node).  Maybe not the most efficient, but incredibly easy to do.
2. Again, if you have some flexibility on the number of files (but not as much as above), you could have one file for the tree structure (so that each node is a fixed size, simplifying its manipulation) and a separate one for storing node contents.  To speed up working with the "content file", you could treat it the way a garbage collecting system would: just keep adding new/updated nodes on the end, marking old nodes as no longer in use, and periodically clearing things out.
3. Better yet, follow @JoachimPileborg's advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the user-specified index to identify the nodes, as that's not directly related to the way you're storing the tree, and you don't have an efficient way of accessing the nodes by index. You should either keep two indices for each node - the user-specified one, and another one that's implementation dependent; or maintain an array mapping the user-specified index to one you're using for the implementation.

Also, it might be better if you use a different structure to store the tree. For each node, store the following:

- the index of the parent
- the index of the leftmost son
- the index of the left brother
- the index of the right brother

This way adding a node and swapping two nodes could be done with some simple pointer manipulations (I don't mean explicit pointers - the indices are somewhat like pointers anyway). Deleting a node would still probably be slow as you have to visit all the children.

As a bonus, if you use this structure, every node has a fixed size (unlike with the linked list you're proposing). This means that you can access a node directly by seeking in the file.

You should also maintain the smallest index the user can use for new nodes - so, for example, even if the largest index was 5 and it was deleted, you still keep 6 as the next free index so 5 cannot be reused.